# Setting up Gzip filter with Jetty 9 (or 7) and Grails

Tags: xml, grails, jetty, gzip

I've been searching the web for posts similar to mine, but I have found no one with the same problem.

I am trying to start a Grails server using Jetty 9, via the command:

> java -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UserCompressedOops -jar server/jetty-runner.rar --port 8080 target/*.war

In the target folder, I have a .war file compiled under the Grails production environment, which I have specified in the Grails config files. I am not using the grails run-app command for testing purposes.

I've followed the instructions on the Jetty web site, http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/gzip-filter.html to no avail.

My jetty-web.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- File: web-app/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml -->

<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<Set name="contextPath">/workpad</Set>

<Call name="setInitParameter">
  <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName</Arg>
  <Arg>none</Arg>
</Call>

<filter>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
    <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</Configure>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to start the server using the command I posted above, the server starts, but only after an IllegalStateException is thrown, saying that the filter tag defining the Gzip filter in the XML file is an unknown tag.

In case it's necessary info, I am using Grails 1.3.7.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The cut and paste for your filter there needs to be located in a web.xml file, not in a jetty-web.xml file...

In other words, that is servlet filter that should be defined in your web application descriptor file. (WEB-INF/web.xml)

The reason it complains about being an unknown tag is that the jetty-web.xml file is a thin skin over java and that is not a valid jetty xml tag.  This is the documentation for that file:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/reference-section.html#jetty-xml-syntax

Comment: I added a web.xml file under WEB-INF/, alongside the jetty-web.xml file, and appended the gzip filter to it. The server starts successfully, but it does not seem to be gzip compressing its responses, as I have verified using Chrome's site details tool.